# What is wrong with this code with interface and abstract class?

Tags: c#

```
interface  inf1{
//interface definition  
}
abstract class  abst{
//abstract definition   
}
public class cls : inf1,abst
{
}
```

I am getting compilation error, But if i interchange the interface and abstarct class it is compiling.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you have a compiler error, it would always be helpful to tell us what it says (if you don't understand what it says on your own). To your specific problem: in c# a base class _must_ be the first element in an inheritance list. That's it, thatswhy it works if it is the first and does not work if you put an interface at the first position.

Comment: Compilation error (line 17, col 27): Base class 'abst' must come before any interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first item after the quotation marks is the class you inherit from. Everything added with commas after the first element MUST be interfaces that you implement.

That is just compiler logic. It simply checks if the following items after the first comma are interfaces. If they are not, it won't compile as you can only inherit from one class.